# Variable becomes undefined after if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code which im trying to use to  any value after the fourth item in the array is zero

```
var wantA = '1120';
wantA = wantA.toString().split('');
wantA = wantA.map(Number);

if (wantA.length >= 4) {
  for (i = 3; i <= wantA.length; i++) {
    var holdb = wantA[i];
    console.log(holdb);
    if (holdb != 0) {
      console.log(holdb);
      alert('error');
    }
  }
}
```

yet looking at the console.log the varibale holdb becomes "undefined" after the if statement even if it was the int 0 before hand

the code should not alert
its also running the if statement console.log twice for some reason

im new to jsfiddle so i hope this works: https://jsfiddle.net/2n8rbjk0/

Comment: The problem is because you're accessing outside the bounds of the array. Also note that if you're trying to get the last item in the array, just use `pop()`

Comment: would that not also remove the last element?

Comment: Yes it would. If you want to get the last but retain the array entities use `wantA[wantA.length - 1]`

Comment: basically this is a logic error, you need to use your inner for loop correctly `for (i = 3; i < wantA.length; i++) ` there is no need to add = operator because we want only this particular element from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for (i=3; i<=wantA.length; i++) should be `i<wantA.length` instead of i<=wantA.length

your loops basically extends beyond the number of elements in array ,

for eg indexes available in array are : 0,1,2,3

Your loops goes for 3 & 4

there is not index 4 hence holdb becomes undefined

Answer (score 1):

It's totally valid to show holdb `undefined` when the value of `i` is **4** because you don't have any element on the array with index **4**, that's why it is showing `undefined` to you. I've added a line that will help you easily understand it. `console.log('when i=' + i + ' then holdb=' + holdb);`

> yet looking at the console.log the variable `holdb` becomes
>   `undefined` after the if statement even if it was the int **0**
>   beforehand

**it's zero when the value of i=3, not 4**

```js
var wantA = "1120"
wantA = wantA.toString().split("");
wantA = wantA.map(Number)

if (wantA.length >= 4) {
  for (i = 3; i <= wantA.length; i++) {
    var holdb = wantA[i]
    console.log('when i=' + i + ' then holdb=' + holdb);
    if (holdb != 0) {
      console.log(holdb);
      alert("error");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When programmer tries to access an element beyond the capacity of index of the array the value is `undefined` is returned as compiler to looks the array with index greater than **array.length**. Therefore in `dynamic` languages like `javascript` **undefined** is returned where as in other staticly/OOP typed languages like Java, C# if you try to access element it throws `indexOutofBoundException` exception trying to access element which is out of range.

- value of array can be access from  array[0-array.length-1] is the range.

Since in your example **wantA**.length is 4 so so **wantA[4]** => trying to access 5th element which is `undefined` that results to make condition **truthy**

```
(function(){
var wantA = '1120';
wantA = wantA.toString().split('');
wantA = wantA.map(Number);

if (wantA.length >= 4) {
  for (i = 3; i < wantA.length; i++) {
    var holdb = wantA[i];
    console.log(holdb);
    if (holdb != 0) { // If (undefined!=0) => results in true therefor alert is occurred.
      console.log(holdb);
      alert('error');
    }
  }
}
}())
```

Answer (score -1):

i did some modification for you code,

```
var wantA = "1120".split("").map(Number);

if (wantA.length >= 4) {
  for (i = 3; i <= wantA.length; i++) {
    if (wantA[3] !== undefined) {
      console.log("holdb", wantA[3]);
    }
  }
}
```